# How does Password reset key work ?

Tags: passwords, password-cracking, password-reset

I mean, [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Password-Reset-Key-including-Password-Windows/dp/B01IA1AKNC/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1475864900&sr=8-1&keywords=Password%20Reset%20Key) looks like a really handy tool for every IT guy out there. But to me, it seems like it does not do anything really hard other than just simplyfing something you can do yourself.

So what exactly does it do and how could you do it manually ?

Comment: I think that I wouldn't buy anything like that unless I could see that others had been using it successfully 8-}

Answer (score 1):

There is a registry key in the SAM database on Windows computers that contains the hash for each password of the local accounts.  The usb drive are bootable, so an admin could boot from that key, it will then mount the system volume, and overwrite the key for the administrator's password.  It will use a hash that matches a "blank" or "no password" for that account.